# Conditonally UPDATE fields with Slick String interpolation

Tags: scala, slick

I have two `Option`s:

```
val name: Option[String] = ...
val shared: Option[Boolean] = ...
```

I would like to build an `UPDATE` query that `SET`s these fields if the above values are `Some`, but leaves them unchanged if they are `None`.

I have managed to achieve this like so, but I am not so keen on the check for the comma, which is not going to scale if I need to add extra columns. I'm also not so keen on having to use a `var`.

```
 var query = Q.u + "UPDATE wishlist SET"
 if(name.isDefined)  query = query + " name = " +? name + (if (share.isDefined) ", " else "")
 if(shared.isDefined) query = query + " shared = " +? share
```

If I wasn't concerned with SQL injection, I could do something along the lines of:

```
 val fields = List(
   name.map(n => s"name = '$n'"),
   shared.map(e => s"shared = $e")
 ).flatten

 s"UPDATE wishlist SET ${fields.mkString(", ")}"
```

**Question:** Is there a nicer way to do this with Slick's plain SQL/String interpolation or is my only option to move to lifted embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not super elegant, but I think it's at least flexible in that it will expand to support many inputs w/o changing the underlying logic:

```
 val name:Option[String] = Some("foo")
 val share:Option[String] = Some("bar")

 val sets = List(
   name.map(n => (" name = ", n)),
   share.map(s => (" shared = ", s))
 ).flatten

 val query2 = sets.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(Q.u + "UPDATE wishlist SET"){
   case (q,(p,0)) => q + p._1 +? p._2
   case (q,(p,i)) => q + "," + p._1 +? p._2
 }
```

I'm putting the field name and value pairs into a list as Options for `Tuple`s and then flattening to remove the `None`s.  I'm then folding to produce the final statement, taking into account that any piece of the query past the first piece will need a comma in it.

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely better.

Comment: Turns out this doesn't work when using mixed types. This is because the `+?` method uses type classes. It uses the type of the argument to look up the associated `SetParameter` instance: `def +? [T](v: T)(implicit p: SetParameter[T])`. In this code if `name` is a `String` and `share` is a `Boolean`, then `sets` becomes a `List[(String,Any)]` and as you can imagine, calling `+?` with an `Any` won't work. As a workaround, I ended up writing a few lines of boilerplate to resolve the type class before `sets` gets created. My code now looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/theon/6215291)