# Slick 3 Updates with Optional Columns

Tags: slick-3.0

Using Slick 3, I want to update my row depending on the property provided by the user. Say, I have 2 properties email and name. If email and name are provided I will update both properties in the database. If either one is provided I will only update the one provided and leave the other untouch.

I found what I want here,

[Conditonally UPDATE fields with Slick String interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152034/conditonally-update-fields-with-slick-string-interpolation)

but I do not want to manipulate the query string directly. Is this the only way? I prefer to use `filter` and `update` methods. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an answer fast enough and I relented. I use multiple update configurations instead of a generalized composing update. This is bad as the number of configurations depend on 2 power of the number of parameters variant. It will become unwieldy and explode. Fortunately, at the moment, I have 2 parameters to manage.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround for this is to get the record first, update its fields in-memory, and then pass it to Slick `update`. It'll generate an SQL UPDATE for all the fields.

Notice that it should be done in transaction and might have different semantics depending on your transaction isolation level.